# Expressing Relationships between Entities Informally

Tags: data-modeling, class-diagram

What are some of the different ways/illustrations people use in order to convey relationships between entities. I'm looking to quickly express relationships between different entities in a sub-system, without getting too complicated; keeping it high level but conveying the relationships clearly. I've heard of and used ERDs in the past, but I'm looking for an alternate solution that:

- Is clear/concise
- Can be quickly mocked, in say, an email
- Conveys the relationships between entities clearly

Comment: :'( no hits on this thread

Comment: For e-mail it may be easiest to describe relationships in text.  Take a look at `Verbalizing Business Rules` by Terry Halpin, pdfs are available on the resources page of www.orm.net